# Autocmd overshadowing?

Tags: vimrc, highlight

I'm using the [`ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace`](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace/) plugin to automatically highlight trailing whitespaces (and removing them). I also want to highlight "irregular" whitespace characters, such as  `(U+00A0)` and so I've added this to my `.vimrc`;

```
highlight IrregularWhitespace ctermbg=red
match IrregularWhitespace / / " U+00A0 (not a traditional space)
autocmd BufWinEnter,CursorMovedI * highlight IrregularWhitespacee ctermbg=red
```

However, if I have the `vim-better-whitespace` plugin enabled, this does not seem to work at all? If I disable the plugin, it works exactly like I want it to.

Comment: You'd better ask to the developer [here](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace/issues)

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking to see that character I believe this will do the trick:

```
set list listchars=nbsp:·
```

You can put whatever character you like after the colon.

See `:h listchars` for more info.

If you wanted to change the hilighting of that character you can  use

```
highlight SpecialKey...
```

But be warned that this will also affect the representation of characters like `^Z` as well.

Comment: That feels like quite a hack though? Am I misunderstanding how autocmd/highlight works or is the plugin actually breaking something?

Comment: `listchars` is fully supported by vim. How is this a hack? I haven't looked at the plugin, as I don't feel like wading through code, but if you feel so inclined, you might check if it also defines the same `autocmd`. I was merely trying to provide you with a simpler way that might not interfere with the plugin.